# Maven Dependencies Not Resolving After Upgrade to Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I recently upgraded my Eclipse from Kepler to Luna.  I now have problems resolving Maven dependencies in my projects.  Specifically, the projects with problems use a repository I need to authenticate to, and the error I'm getting is HTTP 401 Not Authorized error.

If I attempt to run a maven build from the command line, all of the dependencies resolve just fine, so it appears to be a problem with Eclipse or one of its plugins.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  How did you fix it?

Comment: Did U use same workspace?

Comment: I tried with both the old workspace, and a new workspace.  Same problem.

Comment: Does clearing local eclipse .m2 repository solve problem ???